# second entity query is executed with errors

Tags: sql, entity, indexof

I have 2 linq queries. First query does nothing because of unique index and this is OK. But second also does nothing while it should add records . If I bypass first query second query works. Should I refresh entity ? How ?

```
        foreach (var product in productList)
        {
            cc2nexo_SubiektProduct newproduct = new cc2nexo_SubiektProduct();
            newproduct.Name = product.Name;
            newproduct.VAT = product.VAT;
            newproduct.Id = product.Id;
            foreach (var stawkaVAT in myNexo_ExitoEntities.StawkiVat)
            {
                if (stawkaVAT.Stawka * 100 == tryconvert_dec(newproduct.VAT))
                {
                    newproduct.VAT_Id = stawkaVAT.Id;

                }
            }
            myNexo_ExitoEntities.cc2nexo_SubiektProduct.Add(newproduct);
            SurroundWithTryCatchDB(() =>
            {
                myNexo_ExitoEntities.SaveChanges();
            });
        }


        var orders = (from myorders in myNexo_ExitoEntities.temp_SubiektOrderList
                      select myorders).ToList();

        foreach (var order in orders)
        {

            cc2nexo_SubiektOrderList neworder = new cc2nexo_SubiektOrderList();
            neworder.Data_utworzenia_sprawy = tryconvert_date(order.Data_utworzenia_sprawy);
            neworder.Data_modyfikacji_sprawy = tryconvert_date(order.Data_modyfikacji_sprawy);
            neworder.Data_umowy = tryconvert_date(order.Data_umowy);
            neworder.Id = order.Id;
            myNexo_ExitoEntities.cc2nexo_SubiektOrderList.Add(neworder);
            SurroundWithTryCatchDB(() =>
            {
                myNexo_ExitoEntities.SaveChanges();
            });
            Debug.WriteLine(neworder.LastName);
        }
```

I am receiving an error

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.cc2nexo_SubiektProduct' with unique index 'K_ID'. The duplicate key value is (1).The statement has been terminated

Comment: The error message indicates that there is a duplicate key value. Where is this value determined? And how are you ensuring that each row will have a unique key?

Comment: If I run only second query new rows are added to cc2nexo_SubiektOrderList , if I run both queries first query will not add rows to productList ( this is OK because of K_ID index ) but second query is not adding rows ( it looks like SaveChanges still tries to save changes to first query )

Answer (score 0):

The reason of problem was SurroundWithTryCatchDB procedure not listed in my question. Because first query caused exception due to unique index all next SaveChanges did not work. I have changed my first query to work with unique values and now everything is OK.